# Logitech MK710 mouse drops out whilst playing video-games?

Tags: hardware-failure, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have a [Logitech MK710 Wireless keyboard + mouse combo](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/wireless-desktop-mk710). It uses the [Unifying technology](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/promotions/6072) for the receiver.

It worked perfectly since I bought it, with quick response and no noticeable lag. But when I play some video-games I experience signal cuts only in the mouse, for 1-2 seconds. I have the Unifying receiver connected to an USB 2.0 socket in the rear part of my desktop computer, under the table and very close to the mouse and the keyboard.

I have a Wi-Fi router working near the PC, but the computer itself is connected to it using an Ethernet UTP cable. Besides, I only experience the problem while playing video-games.

Both keyboard and mouse batteries are the provided ones, Energizer not-rechargeable. And both battery indicators are full.

I think the problem is not related with a signal interference, because it only happens while playing video-games. It seems that the keyboard has no signal cuts ever, even when playing video-games.

**Is anyone experiencing the same issue? What is the problem? How can I solve it?**

#### My PC:

- **OS:** Windows 8.1 (up-to-date)
- **Motherboard:** Asus Gryphon Z87,
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-4771,
- **RAM:** G.Skill Ripjaws X DDR3 1866 PC3-14900 16GB 2x8GB CL9,
- **Graphics:** Asus GTX 760 DC 2GB GDDR5)

All the drivers up-to-date. The game I'm playing is Battlefield 3 Premium (on Origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to last Unifying software and it solved the problem. It seems that Windows 8 (or Windows 8.1) auto-detect the Unifying receiver and both keyboard and mouse, but the default driver is not working properly. Now, with the specific Logitech software, it seems to work as expected, even playing video-games.